# f4v convert with FFMPEG

Tags: flash-media-server

I create a flash application. This application send video and microphone stream to fms app, fms app store stream and create .f4v file.

How to convert FMS(ver.5) .f4v stream file to mpeg or avi with FFMPEG or other tool ?

Thanks
Gabor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

> ffmpeg -i input.f4v ouput.avi

or

> ffmpeg -i input.f4v ouput.mpg

If you want to check if your ffmpeg version support f4v type:

> ffmpeg -formats